# Can I use git in a server-bound mode, without keeping the full history locally?

Tags: git, client-server

I'm using GIT on my main development machine which has a huge hard disk and I barely notice that I've got a full copy of the history right there. (This is a big selling point of GIT, being able to work offline without access to a shared server.)

However, I also have a tablet with a copy of Notepad++ and not much free space left. I'd like to use GIT here as well but I'm not going to have enough space to keep the full history.

Can I use GIT in such a way that my local storage just keeps my current working files and instead goes to my GIT server for commits, etc?

I understand this will come at the cost of not being able to work when I'm disconnected from that server.

Comment: You can use a "shallow clone": https://www.perforce.com/blog/141218/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones

Comment: @ceejayoz - You should make that an answer rather than a comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Git shallow clone.

https://www.perforce.com/blog/141218/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git jquery
```

> The above command clones only the current HEAD of the jQuery repository on GitHub. An unscientific comparison shows that it completes in a couple of seconds compared to the roughly thirty-plus seconds it takes to clone the entire repository without the depth switch, a savings of more than 90%. That one trick can relieve a great deal of load from servers that are pulled frequently via automation.
>
> Users should also be aware that shallow clones were quite limited in their functionality prior to Git v1.9. With v1.9 and later, however, Git has been improved to support pull and push operations even with shallow clones. This allows changes to be made and committed/pushed back to the source repository if needed as part of automated build operations.